# Basic Vue question: Integrating fullpage.js wrapper with other behaviors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullpage.js

**Update* I've added a Codepen here, documenting the issue: https://codepen.io/nickpish/pen/MRJVMe

I'm quite new to Vue, and I'm working on a project using the [Fullpage.js Vue wrapper](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/vue-fullpage.js). While I have the Fullpage functionality working, I'm having trouble integrating other behaviors, such as this basic animation-on-scroll function [detailed here](https://codepen.io/kode88/pen/vmYeew). The `handleScroll()` method coupled with the `v-on` directive on the `h2` element should simply add a class to trigger an animation. My template code is as follows:

```
<template>
    <full-page ref="fullpage" :options="options" id="fullpage">
        <div class="section">
            <h3 :class="{'bounceInLeft': scrolled}" v-on="handleScroll" class="animated">{{scrolled}}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <div class="slide">
                <h3>Slide 2.1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h3>Slide 2.2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h3>Slide 2.3</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section">
            <h3>Section 3</h3>
        </div>
    </full-page>
</template>
```

And my Vue instance, returning options for the Fullpage component, along with defining the scrolling animation methods and `scrolled` data property are as follows:

```
// create vue instance w/ fullpage
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            scrolled: false,
            options: {
                navigation: true,
                menu: '#nav-menu',
                anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3'],
                sectionsColor: ['#41b883', '#ff5f45', '#0798ec', '#fec401', '#1bcee6', '#ee1a59', '#2c3e4f', '#ba5be9', '#b4b8ab']
            },
        }
    },
    methods: {
        handleScroll() {
            let obj = document.querySelector('h3');
            let {top,bottom} = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
            let height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            this.scrolled = top < height && bottom >0;
        }
    },
    created() {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    },
    destroyed() {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
});
```

I'm clearly not implementing the `scrolled` property and/or related method correctly, as it simply retains a value of `false` and does not change on scroll. How can I get this value to change, and apply the class, as desired? Thanks for any assistance here- and please let me know if the question is unclear in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the goal is to apply the `bounceInLeft` class dynamically when a section appears into view. For this to work, we need to track each section individually. The scrolled boolean has been expanded to an object with properties named according to the sections and in this case, `page1`, `page2`, `page3`.

```
<h3 :class="{'bounceInLeft': scrolled.page1}" class="animated">{{scrolled.page1}}</h3>
```

Next, add the `scrolled` object to your data use the `afterLoad` callback to mutate the appropriate scrolled page boolean.

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: function() {
        return {
            scrolled: {
                page1: false,
                page2: false,
                page3: false
            },
            options: {
                licenseKey: null,
                afterLoad: this.afterLoad,
                navigation: true,
                anchors: ["page1", "page2", "page3"],
                sectionsColor: ["#41b883", "#ff5f45", "#0798ec"]
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        afterLoad: function(origin, destination, direction) {
            const { top, bottom } = destination.item.getBoundingClientRect();
            const height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            this.scrolled[destination.anchor] = top < height && bottom > 0;
        }
    }
});
```

https://codepen.io/RichardAyotte/pen/axpKoQ

Comment: Hm, that still doesn't do it- value remains `false`. Is there some other way I should be adding the `scrolled` property to `data` in the Vue instance?

Comment: I've actually created a full Codepen documenting the issue here, forking the one from vue-fullpage - https://codepen.io/nickpish/pen/MRJVMe  Thanks for your help here!

Comment: I see. I think this is what you're looking for https://codepen.io/RichardAyotte/pen/axpKoQ

Comment: Thanks- that's interesting; so it needed to be incorporated using one of fullpage's callbacks? Please feel free to revise your answer above, and I can mark it as selected. Thanks again.

Comment: @nickpish glad I could help!

Comment: Another option is to just use the fullpage.js option `scrollBar:true` and then any code based on the scroll position should work as normal :)